# How to prove if the following series converges or diverges $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I tried to prove or disprove if the following series converges or diverges: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$ for every $a>0$.

I used the Root Test and the limit equals to "$a$". So, I thought the answer is if $a>1$ the series diverges, if $a<1$ the series converges and I checked when $a=1$ it is harmonic series with power above $1$ so it also converges. I am afraid it is wrong because it looks too much naive. There is something to worry about?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $a=1$, then the series becomes $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n\sqrt[n]n}$, which is *not* the harmonic series.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos why? In the denominator, we have only n power (1+1/n).

Comment: And the harmonic series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$, which is not the same thing as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n\sqrt[n]n}$.

Comment: The harmonic series has power $1$, not $1+1/n$. But we can *compare* it the harmonic series: $\sqrt[n]{n}<2$ for all $n\ge1$ so the partial sums grow faster than that of $\sum\frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: DanielMa, why did you delete [your last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725070)? It was interesting and its closure as an alledged duplicate was a mistake. I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Apply the [root test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)
on $u_n=\frac{a^n}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$

$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}(u_n)^{\frac 1 n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{n^{\frac 1 n}}\\&=a\end{align}$

---

For $a=1$ , use limit comparison test.

Let $v_n=\frac{1}{n}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}=1$

Hence for $a=1$ , $\sum_{n}\frac{a^n}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}$ diverges.